# MySQL DML operation using executeBatch vs in operator

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-update

If I have to update a table's field to a particular (same) value for 100 records. Which one of the below method is faster and preferred?

**1. Using Prepared statement**

```
String query = "update employee set status='A' where empId = ?"; 
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    Long empId = list.get(i);
    pStmt.setLong(1, empId);
    pStmt.addBatch();
}
pStmt.executeBatch();
```

**2. Using in operator**

```
StringBuilder query = "update employee set status='A' where empId in (";
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    Long empId = list.get(i);
    query.append(empId).append(",");
}
query.setLength(query.length() - 1);
query.append(")");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query.toString());
```

Comment: Likely the second, but you should test it and see.

Comment: The second will be hands down faster